# Find value in array from key

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array (Dates) of 600 items like this:
`[{Case: 1, Date: 01012019},{Case: 2, Date: 01022019},{Case: 3, Date: 01032019}`

What is the best approach to get the value from the key "Date" based on the key "Case"?

I know I can do a simple loop ($.each())on the array and break out of the loop once i find the key I'm looking for. Another option - as far as I've read at least - is to use the $.map() function.

I will need to lookup the key for 50-100 items on page load, so looping the array (Dates) seems like a lot of work to get me there. Is there a more efficient way? Og talking javescript/Jquery here :)

Comment: I assume the `Case` numbers are just placeholders right, they're not actually in predictable order in your real code?

Comment: Yup case numbers are in random order :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the array into an object indexed by `Case` first, and then instead of using a `for` loop or `.find` to find the associated object each time, just use object property lookup to find the associated object:

```js
const dates = [{
  Case: 1,
  Date: 01012019
}, {
  Case: 2,
  Date: 01022019
}, {
  Case: 3,
  Date: 01032019
}];

const datesByCase = dates.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.Case] = item;
  return a;
}, {});

// now say we want to find objects associated with case 2 and 3:
console.log(datesByCase['2']);
console.log(datesByCase['3']);
```

For N Cases to find, this has `O(N)` complexity overall. (Using a `for` loop for every `Case` you want to find has `O(N^2)` complexity overall)

Comment: Thanks - this is an area I'm not really been using so forgive me, if it's a dumb question but I only need to do this once right? Also what does "const" mean in this context?

Comment: `const` is very similar to `var`, except that it's more predictable and easier to read - it has block scope, and indicates that the variable in question will not be reassigned. Yes, you only need to reduce into an object once (as you can see on the final two lines, you can look up `datesByCase` as many times as you want after the object is created)

Comment: @CertainPerformance will converting it to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) make the access faster ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee No - both Maps and objects have `O(1)` property lookup complexity (at least in any remotely sane implementation)

Comment: What am I doing wrong when this doesnt work (internalCases is the array)     const modifiedByCase = internalCases.reduce((a, item) => {
      a[item.Case] = item;
      return a;
     }, {});

Comment: @MortenK That looks exactly equivalent to the code I used to create `datesByCase`, so it should work. What problems are you having with it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hmm it does seem to work in Chrome now (after i corrected the array name), but it still throws an error in IE. Edit: Ok just read up on the const it seems IE does not suport it!

Comment: @MortenK Best to write in the latest and greatest version of the language for ease of development and transpile down to ES5 for obsolete browsers later. Run the code through [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) first

Comment: Unfortunately I need it solely to be working on IE as it's an solution that only needs to run internally where we (more or less) restrict the users to use IE (Trust me we have our reasons for this even if it seems odd)...

Comment: That's OK, you can still use Babel to transpile the code - even if I was writing code for IE, I'd still write in ESNext and transpile later :)

Answer (score 0):

If cases are unique try to convert array into object, that help you to avoid looping every time:

convert like this :

```js
const dates = [{
  Case: 1,
  Date: 01012019
}, {
  Case: 2,
  Date: 01022019
}, {
  Case: 3,
  Date: 01032019
}];
let obj = {};
dates.map((date)=>obj[date.Case]=date.Date);
console.log(obj);
console.log('case "1" date is '+obj["1"]);
```